# Two lists interact in python

Tags: python, maya

This is a Maya Python question.

[image]

How do I create a for loop that make this

[image]

I create two lists, one for Buffer and one for MM.
with this command, cmds.connectAttr(MM +'.messeage', buffer+'.renderPass', f=True)

you can connect MM to buffer

[image]

Here is what I current have:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import maya.mel as mel
import random as rand
import math

bufferls=[]
MMls=[]



for i in range(5):

    writeToColor=mel.eval('mrCreateCustomNode -asUtility "" writeToColorBuffer;')
    cmds.rename(writeToColor, 'buffer'+str(i))    
    bufferls.append('buffer'+str(i))

for i in range(2):
    MutiMatte = cmds.createNode( 'renderPass', name=('MM'+str(i)))         
    cmds.setRenderPassType( 'MM'+str(i),type='CSTCOL')
    MMls.append(MutiMatte)



def n_split(bufferls, n=3):
    num_extra = len(bufferls) % n
    zipped = zip(*[iter(bufferls)] * n)
    return zipped if not num_extra else zipped + [bufferls[-num_extra:], ]


for buffer in n_split(bufferls, 3):
    newlists =list(buffer)
    print newlists
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over `listA` using enumerate, and then use slices to get the bits from `listB`:

```
def pair_in_groups(listA, listB, n):
    for i, item in enumerate(listA):
        yield (item, listB[n*i: n*(i+1)])

listA = ['mm0', 'mm1', 'mm2']
listB = ['aa1', 'aa2', 'aa3','aa4','aa5']

for pair in pair_in_groups(listA, listB, 3):
    print(pair)
```

prints

```
('mm0', ['aa1', 'aa2', 'aa3'])
('mm1', ['aa4', 'aa5'])
('mm2', [])
```